# How to set the value from the drop down as the default value in the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the set default value of the select to **month**. Moreover on load select should show **month** as text instead of Filter.
How can it be achieved???
any help would do good.

Below is the snippet of the code I have written so far.

```js
function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
  .dropbtn {
          background-color: #3498DB;
          position: relative;
            margin: 0 20px;
          color: white;
          padding: 3px 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
          border: none;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
          background-color: #2980B9;
        }
    
        .dropdown {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
    
        }
    
        .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
          min-width: 130px;
          box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          z-index: 1;
        }
    
        .dropdown-content a {
          color: black;
          padding: 12px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          display: block;
        }
    
        .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
          .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
          .show {display:block;}
```

```html
 
<div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Filter </button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Day</a>
                  <a href="#">Week</a>
                  <a href="#">Month</a>
                </div>
```

Please let me know how i can achieve this

Comment: can you create a working snippet to see it in action?

Comment: Is there any reason why you haven't used a `<select>`?

Comment: @JamesS No, not actually

Comment: I would suggest using that for dropdowns

Comment: @JamesS these days it's imposible to make a select look like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can apply click event on the links and when clicked the value of filter can be set

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropbtn").html($(".default").text())
})
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $("#myDropdown").children('a').click(function(){
    $('.dropbtn').html($(this).text())
    })
```

```css
.dropbtn {
      background-color: #3498DB;
      position: relative;
        margin: 0 20px;
      color: white;
      padding: 3px 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
      background-color: #2980B9;
    }

    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;

    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 130px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
      .show {display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Filter </button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Day</a>
              <a href="#">Week</a>
              <a href="#" class="default">Month</a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 makes this more easier by using the select tag.
The `selected` option will specify which option has to be selected by default when the page loads.

```
<select>
    <option value="Day">Day</option>
    <option value="Week">Week</option>
    <option value="Month" selected >Month</option>
<select>
```

Comment: How do you think some action will be performed after selecting any of it?

Comment: There, i have a href and here?

Comment: You can give an `id` for the select tag and use that id in your javascript. For eg: `<select id="dropdown">`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that div class you've got. Create a dropdown such as the following.

```
<select>
    <option value="Day">Day</option>
    <!--etc-->
</select>
```

To make a default using this you can simply add the following

```
    <option value="Day" selected="selected">Day</option>
```